# All viewed pages data until transaction from Google Analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics, web-analytics

I want to get the page view data from Google Analytics using R. I am using googleAnalyticsR package for getting these data using R.

Currently, I can get the `landingPagePath, secondPagePath, previousPagePath, exitPagePath` information. But I want to get the whole viewed pages in that session which transaction occurred. For instance, let's say a visitor came to the my website and logged in. After that s/he visited in pages titled as below in a given order

Page1 > Page2 > Page1 > Category > Product12 > Product13 > Basket > Checkout

I want to get this view flow as it is. I cannot do it using google analytics api's metrics & dimensions for page tracking.

How can I get the full 'view flow' data? Can I create such a report using only google analytics reports? Or should I try something else?

Thanks for any advice,

Best.

Answer (score 0):

Google Analytics is basically a database where every hit (pageview, event, etc) is a single row. Try fetching these dimensions:
Page
Date, Hour, Minute, Second
metrics:
Pageviews

sort by Date, Hour, Minute, Second

Once you got all the data, create logic in R finding most common pathes.

Normally, BigQuery is used for such tasks (if you have Analytics 360 - GMP, payed version off GA). In BigQuery you have hit number

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I used pagePath, Date, Hour, Minute and pageviews but I what I get is number of visits in a given time for pages. I cannot find any path with this data because I cannot group those visits. I want to catch the customer via its transactionId and fetch the urls or titles of the pages s/he visited starting from the beginning of the session. I also tried multi channel funneling type using campaignPath and keywordPath separately as dimensions. But most of the lines include (unavailable) results. Do you have any other suggestions?